# isLabelProperty() not being called

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm making an Eclipse RCP application that should refresh only a part of a `TreeViewer` that has `TreeViewerColumns`, which in turn have `ColumnLabelProviders` that override the `isLabelProperty(Object, String)` method.

As expected, I am using the `TreeViewer.update(Object, String[])` when I want to update only one column, and the `String[]` looks like this: `new String[]{"propertyName"}`

All the columns are being updated, despite calling the update method with properties in it.

**After debugging I have concluded that the `isLabelProperty` method is not called.**

This is using JFace 3.8.0

Answer (score 2):

Tracing through the code it appears that even though you are using ColumnLabelProviders the `update` method still looks at the default `LabelProvider` when it is doing the `isLabelProperty` test.

You could try using `setLabelProvider` with a label provider that just does the `isLabelProperty` method.

Comment: which LabelProvider are you referring to? My own implementation with stubs everywhere except the isLabelProperty method?

Comment: Just extend `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider` and override `isLabelProperty`.